# Method unit testing failing in nestjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have below only method in my controller.

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  
  @Get('whoami')
    @Roles(Role.All)
    @ApiResponse({ status: 200, type: User })
    currentUser(@Req() request: Request) {
        return request.user;
    }
}
```

I am writing below test case for the same.

```
describe('AppController', () => {
    let controller: AppController;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [AppController],
        }).compile();

        controller = app.get<AppController>(AppController);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('currentUser should be called', () => {
        expect(controller.currentUser).toBeDefined();
        expect(controller.currentUser).toEqual("shruti");
    });
});
```

not only this is failing but also  `return request.user;` not getting covered in coverage. below is the error.

[image]

what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller.currentUser` is a function. It takes in the `Request` object and returns `request.user`. Your test should look something like

```js
    it('currentUser should be called', () => {
        expect(controller.currentUser).toBeDefined();
        expect(controller.currentUser({ user: "shruti" } as any)).toEqual("shruti");
    });
```

The `as any` is necessary here because `Request` has way more properties than just `user` but all your test and code care about is that `user` is there to be returned.